# Factory Pattern question

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I'm taking a stab at using the factory method for the first time. It seems like there are 2 ways to do it and I'm not sure when to use which (or if one of them is wrong?).

1) Create an abstract class that has a method that is overridden by subclasses:

```
public abstract class EmployeeCreator
{
    public abstract Employee FactoryMethod();
}

public class DeveloperCreator : EmployeeCreator
{
    public override Employee FactoryMethod()
    {
        return new Developer();
    }
}
```

2) Create a class with one factory method in it:

```
public class EmployeeFactory
{
    public static Employee CreateEmployee(EmployeeType type)
    {
        if (type == EmployeeType.Developer)
            return new Developer();
        else
            return new Secretary();
    }
}
```

It seems like in my case #2 is going to be a lot easier because I won't have to create all of these "creator" subclasses that really don't do much other than return the right type of the employee.

But is it still using a factory pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first case is the [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern, while the 2nd is [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). These are two different patterns, both are valid and useful. (There is no "Factory pattern" actually - whenever you hear this term, it is a reference to one of the patterns mentioned above.)

If you only have a single product to create, Factory Method is usually a better choice. If you have (any chance of) the need to create a family of related products, you need Abstract Factory. The latter is also better if you need to inject your factory to different places in your code, as it is better to have a distinct interface for this purpose.

Comment: 100% agree, for your case you should go for case two.

Comment: According to the Head First Design Patterns book, wouldn't the first be an example of a simple factory and the second be a factory? Abstract factories are for families of products, no?

Comment: @Joe, in your first example, the family has a single member, that's all. IMHO this doesn't deserve a separate name. You still have the abstract base class / interface and separate concrete factory subclass(es), and that's the main point of the pattern.

Comment: Shoot, I meant to refer to the second example actually as being a simple factory. And yes, I do see now that the first is an abstract factory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure which way is "right," but I can tell you that your second option is going to be much more useful in your scenario, as you have stated.  I try to use a static creation method in the abstract base class when I can so that the right subclass is instantiated based on the necessary logic.  It sounds like that's what you are trying to do also, and I don't see any problem with that.

Remember that the design patterns are there as a guide to solve problems and to help maintainability through standardization.  If you find something that maintains the same "spirit" but suits your needs better for some discernible reason, I see no reason not to go for it.

Comment: Thanks. And you said you create your factory method within the abstract base class (in my case Employee)? I think I will do that as well since it seems pointless to have a class for just one factory method. What do you typically call your method e.g. EmployeeFactory, CreateEmployee, GetEmployee...?

Comment: @Joe Usually just something like CreateEmployee, but use whatever fits your code standards and conventions.